# Is it faster to create a new object reference if it will only be used twice?

Tags: java, object, optimization, reference, casting

I have a question about instruction optimization. If an object is to be used in two statements, is it faster to create a new object reference or should I instead call the object directly in both statements?

For the purposes of my question, the object is part of a `Vector` of objects (this example is from a streamlined version of Java without ArrayLists). Here is an example:

```
AutoEvent ptr = ((AutoEvent)e_autoSequence.elementAt(currentEventIndex));
if(ptr.exitConditionMet()) {currentEventIndex++; return;}
ptr.registerSingleEvent();
```

`AutoEvent` is the class in question, and `e_autoSequence` is the `Vector` of AutoEvent objects. The `AutoEvent` contains two methods in question: `exitConditionMet()` and `registerSingleEvent()`.

This code could, therefore, alternately be written as:

```
if(((AutoEvent)e_autoSequence.elementAt(currentEventIndex)).exitConditionMet()) 
    {currentEventIndex++; return;}
((AutoEvent)e_autoSequence.elementAt(currentEventIndex)).registerSingleEvent();
```

Is this faster than the above?

I understand the casting process is slow, so this question is actually twofold: additionally, in the event that I am not casting the object, which would be more highly optimized?

Bear in mind this is solely for two uses of the object in question.

Comment: The costly operation here is likely to be getting the object out of the `Vector`, not assigning the result to a variable.  So the first solution should be faster.

Comment: This seems like a very petty thing to be optimizing. Even *considering* the performance hit for mere casting seems a little wrong to me. You seem to indicate that you're running on a "streamlined" version of Java, so perhaps you're working in a mobile environment, or similar, but I'd still question whether this optimization is really necessary. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JakeKing It's honestly more of a curiosity than anything. I do understand it makes little to no actual difference, especially given the trivial size of the Vector. Still curious, though.

Comment: @JakeKing - there are plenty of situations where this kind of optimisation can be very important. I've doubled the overall speed of CPU-bound code many times with little optimisations like this. It doesn't always matter (you should profile first if in doubt!), but when it does matter it is definitely worth doing.

Comment: Frankly the best advice I've heard is "Write Java, write idiomatic Java, and let the compiler figure out the details". The compiler looks for common patterns that folks do and optimizes it as best it can, so playing games and questioning the compiler is mostly counterproductive.

Comment: @Will : That's great advice in general. Just be aware that there are many situations where it isn't true - if you really care about performance, you absolutely need to understand when the compiler knows best, and when it doesn't (in this situation, it doesn't, i.e. it won't convert the second code sample into the first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is better all round:

- **Only one call** to the vector `elementAt` method. This is actually the most expensive operation here, so only doing it once is a decent performance win. Also doing it twice potentially opens you up to some race conditions.
- **Only one cast** operation. Casts are very cheap on moderns JVMs, but still have a slight cost.
- It's **more readable** IMHO. You are getting an object then doing two things with it. If you get it twice, then the reader has to mentally figure out that you are getting the same object. Better to get it once, and assign it to a variable with a good name.
- A *single assignment of a local variable* (like `ptr` in the first solution) is **extremely cheap and often free** - the Java JIT compiler is smart enough to produce highly optimised code here.

P.S. `Vector` is pretty outdated. Consider converting to an `ArrayList<AutoEvent>`. By using the generic ArrayList you won't need to explicitly cast, and it is much faster than a `Vector` (because it isn't synchronised and therefore has less locking overhead)

Comment: +1 for the "readable" argument. This way, the reader is not left with the nagging question "but does this method call *really* give me the same object every time".

Answer (score 0):

First solution will be faster.

The reason is that assignments work faster than method invocations.
In the second case you will have method elementAt() invoked twice, which will make it slower and JVM will probably not be able to optimize this code because it doesn't know what exactly is happening in the elementAt().

Also remember that Vector's methods are synchronized, which makes every method invocation even slower due to lock acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by "create a new object reference" here.  The following code `((AutoEvent)e_autoSequence.elementAt(currentEventIndex))` probably will be translated into bytecode that obtains sequence element, casts it to `AutoEven` and store the resulting reference on stack.  Local variable `ptr` as other local variables is stored on stack too, so assigning reference to is is just copying 4 bytes from one stack slot to another, nearby stack slot.  This is very-very fast operation.  Modern JVMs do not do reference counting, so assigning references is probably as cheap as assigning `int` values.

Answer (score 0):

Lets get some terminology straight first.  Your code does not "create a new object reference".  It is fetching an existing object reference (either once or twice) from a `Vector`.

---

To answer your question, it is (probably) a little bit faster to fetch once and put the reference into a temporary variable.  But the difference is small, and *unlikely* to be significant unless you do it lots of times in a loop.

(The `elementAt` method on a `Vector` or `ArrayList` is `O(1)` and cheap.  If the list was a linked list, which has an `O(N)` implementation for `elementAt`, then that call could be expensive, and the difference between making 1 or 2 calls could be significant ...)

Generally speaking, you should think about the complexity of your algorithms, but beyond that you shouldn't spend time optimizing ... until you have solid profiling evidence to tell you where to optimize.

---

I can't say whether `ArrayList` would be more appropriate.  This could be a case where you *need* the thread-safety offered by `Vector`.